# How add Event EventHandler in xaml?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have custom Picker with property

```
public EventHandler SelectedIndexChanged { get; set; }
```

and i want set this property from xaml. 
like this  `GenderPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += GenderPicker_OnSelectedIndexChanged;`
 but from xaml

```
    <elements:CustomPicker 
  SelectedIndexChanged="{What write there???}"/>
```

Comment: its didnt work, because Control wait Value, but not Property.<elements:CustomPicker 
  SelectedIndexChanged="GenderPicker_OnSelectedIndexChanged"/>

Answer (score 2):

Just write the name of the method like `Handle_SelectedIndexChanged` and make sure that you create the method in your code-behind of the page where you are using the control, with the right signature, for instance:

```
private void Handle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // ... your code here
}
```

Comment: its custom renderer
its didnt work, because Control wait Value, but not Property.<elements:CustomPicker SelectedIndexChanged="GenderPicker_OnSelectedIndexChanged"/>

Comment: Custom Element visible its property like text

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just press tab after you select an event handler and it will auto generate it in the code behind for you to add whatever logic you want. However, you if you are trying to use bindings it is slightly more complicated. You will need an ItemsSource.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedIndexChanged}"
```

In the view model you will also need-

```
public PickerFlyout Foo { get; set; }
```

And in the start you will need initialize what is in the picker.